# Button don't react for tap and click keywords in ios, robotframework

Tags: react-native, robotframework, appium-ios

I have a native application for android and ios. I write e2e tests in robot framework. 
 
My problem is that in ios, when I want to click on a button, it doesn't react. If I want a click, on a textfield, the keyboard shows, so it reacted. When I use manually, the button reacts for the click. I tried every click stimulating keywords from appium library, but the result was the same. 
 
Did anyone get have this problem already? 
 
Can it be something with the keyword implementation, or eith the button? (react-native-button).

**Solved**
The structure was:
......
And somehow the Row and Cole elements captured the tap and I deleted it and designed the Button with style.

Comment: Does the logs show that the button was clicked?

Comment: In the logs, there are nothing weird. The test clicks and waits to the next element, which has to be shown after this click, but it does not appears. You can see the causes in my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Click Button** instead of **Click Element**

http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Click%20Button

Comment: I tried every types of tap and click keywords. I already get the source of the problem, now I search for solution. The problem is that the button is in a Col element, which is inside in a Row. It is for positioning. 
These items cover somehow the button. If I remove, the Col and Row, the button reacts to the tap, but the positioning is tampered.